# Scrapy not working (noob level) - 0 pages crawled 0 items crawled

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to follow the Scrapy tutorial but I stuck and have no idea where is mistake.
It is working but no items are crawled.

I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\xxx\allegro>scrapy crawl AllegroPrices
2017-12-10 22:25:14 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: AllegroPrices)
2017-12-10 22:25:14 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'allegro.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['allegro.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'BOT_NAME': 'AllegroPrices'}
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'allegro.middlewares.AllegroSpiderMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['allegro.pipelines.AllegroPipeline']
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [AllegroPrices] INFO: Spider opened: AllegroPrices
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 10, 21, 25, 15, 527000),
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 10, 21, 25, 15, 517000)}
2017-12-10 22:25:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

My spider file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from allegro.items import AllegroItem

class AllegroPrices(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AllegroPrices"
    allowed_domains = ["allegro.pl"]

#Use working product URL below
start_urls = [
 "http://allegro.pl/diablo-ii-lord-of-destruction-2-pc-big-box-eng-i6896736152.html", "http://allegro.pl/diablo-ii-2-pc-dvd-box-eng-i6961686788.html",
 "http://allegro.pl/star-wars-empire-at-war-2006-dvd-box-i6995651106.html", "http://allegro.pl/heavy-gear-ii-2-pc-eng-cdkingpl-i7059163114.html"
 ]

def parse(self, response):
    items = AllegroItem()
    title = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]//text()').extract()
    sale_price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]//text()').extract()
    seller = response.xpath('//div[@class="btn btn-default btn-user"]/span/text()').extract()
    items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
    items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
    items['product_seller'] = ''.join(seller).strip()
    yield items
```

Settings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for allegro project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'AllegroPrices'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['allegro.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'allegro.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'allegro (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'allegro.middlewares.AllegroSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}

LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'allegro.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'allegro.pipelines.AllegroPipeline': 300,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Pipeline:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


class AllegroPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Items:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy

class AllegroItem(scrapy.Item):
  # define the fields for your item here like:
  product_name = scrapy.Field()
  product_sale_price = scrapy.Field()
  product_seller = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: I have no problem to run as standalone script without creating project (PL: nie mam problemu z uruchomieniem tego jako samodzielny skrypt bez tworzenia projektu)

Comment: I think you have wrong indentions - `start_urls` and `parse()` have to be inside class `AllegroPrices`. Now they are not inside. Indentions are very important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem to run it as standalone script without creating project and save to CSV file.

And I don't have to change `USER-AGENT`.

Maybe there is problem with some settings. You didn't put url to tutorial to check it.

Or simply you have wrong indentions and `start_urls` and `parse()` in not inside class. Indentions are very important in Python.

BTW: you forgot `/a/` in `xpath` for seller.

```
import scrapy

#class AllegroItem(scrapy.Item):
#    product_name = scrapy.Field()
#    product_sale_price = scrapy.Field()
#    product_seller = scrapy.Field()

class AllegroPrices(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "AllegroPrices"
    allowed_domains = ["allegro.pl"]

    start_urls = [
        "http://allegro.pl/diablo-ii-lord-of-destruction-2-pc-big-box-eng-i6896736152.html",
        "http://allegro.pl/diablo-ii-2-pc-dvd-box-eng-i6961686788.html",
        "http://allegro.pl/star-wars-empire-at-war-2006-dvd-box-i6995651106.html",
        "http://allegro.pl/heavy-gear-ii-2-pc-eng-cdkingpl-i7059163114.html"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]//text()').extract()
        sale_price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]//text()').extract()
        seller = response.xpath('//div[@class="btn btn-default btn-user"]/a/span/text()').extract()

        title = title[0].strip()

        print(title, sale_price, seller)

        yield {'title': title, 'price': sale_price, 'seller': seller}

        #items = AllegroItem()
        #items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
        #items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
        #items['product_seller'] = ''.join(seller).strip()
        #yield items

# --- run it as standalone script without project and save in CSV ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

#c = CrawlerProcess()

c = CrawlerProcess({
#    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv'
})

c.crawl(AllegroPrices)
c.start()
```

Result in CSV file:

```
title,price,seller
STAR WARS: EMPIRE AT WAR [2006] DVD BOX,"24,90 zł",CDkingpl
DIABLO II: LORD OF DESTRUCTION 2 PC BIG BOX ENG,"149,00 zł",CDkingpl
HEAVY GEAR II 2 | PC ENG CDkingpl,"19,90 zł",CDkingpl
DIABLO II 2 | PC DVD BOX | ENG,"24,90 zł",CDkingpl
```

Comment: This is url to tutorial: http://blog.datahut.co/tutorial-how-to-scrape-amazon-using-python-scrapy/